# jQuery CSS executes after the command following it

Tags: jquery, css

I have a container and an inner div taking 100% of the container's width. I want the container to expand instantly, but keep the inner div at its currents dimensions and later expand it gradually using CSS transition. Here's the original [JS Fiddle no. 1](http://jsfiddle.net/3oyskrhg/1/).

As that doesn't seem to work (why?), even though CSS should be applied instantly, I try to delay the `addClass` on the container with this [JS Fiddle no. 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3oyskrhg/2/), which doesn't work either.

And finally, after setting a longer delay to the previous fiddle, it works with 1000ms instead of 100ms. So `.css()` takes effect after 1000ms, but doesn't after 100ms?!

Can anyone tell me why the `.css()` function behaves as if it works asynchronously?

Answer (score 5):

For the #1 to work, you need this code, take the `.css()` out of the `setTimeout`:

```
$('.inner').css({
  width: $('.inner').width() + 'px',
  height: $('.inner').height() + 'px'
});
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.container').addClass('big');
}, 1000);
```

You have wrapped everything inside `setTimeout` with `1000` ms, instead of `$(function () {});`.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m7k9mre8/**

Comment: Unfortunately, the only reason it works is because you have a 1000ms delay in the setTimeout following the command. Try with 100ms in setTimeout and it won't work, here's the fiddle where I changed only that:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7k9mre8/1/)

Comment: @BlacksmithBG Lemme check the jQuery bugs or intimate them about this issue! Wow.

Comment: I appreciate that. If you have a workaround you can suggest in the meantime, that would also be helpful because I'm stuck with this one in a bigger project. I simply need the container to expand instantly and the inner div to follow it gradually.

Comment: @BlacksmithBG Looks like this is an issue with the jQuery and browser too! Do you really want this to happen on load?

Comment: I want it to happen on click. Still doesn't work.
Also, as I was looking for a workaround, I realized that the problem might be with animating from % to px or whatever. I solved it by initializing width explicitly on the inner item (inline style), and only after it's been firmly set :) do I expand the container. Then it works.